# asp.net mvc controller factory

Tags: asp.net-mvc, policy-injection, controller-factory

I would like to achieve something to this extent:

1. I want to audit all of my controllers participating in serving http requests to the view files.
2. I would like to audit each and every method on that controller and write this information to the flat file (rolling logger??).
3. The audit log should contain: `authenticated user` info, `method called`, `method parameters`, `time stamp`.

I realize that this would require implementing my own controller factory to do something like this:

```
    //policy injection call that is set up to log all the methods, called on the 
   //controller.
   var myController = ControllerCustomerFactory<FlatRollingLogger>.Create();
```

what should I do next, should I inject the custom created controller somewhere else or the factory will keep track on which controller needs to be instantiated?

I was thinking Microsoft Ent Lib Policy Injection as it has been done for other auditing purposes in our company?

Any other better ideas to handle this?

merci

Comment: Why not use a global filter and log all that stuff `OnActionExecuting`

Answer (score 3):

No, you don't need your own factory controller, just create a global action filter.  MVC is very extensible.

http://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/archive/2010/08/15/asp-net-mvc-3-global-action-filters.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You might want to consider an aspect oriented approach using a framework such as [PostSharp](http://www.sharpcrafters.com/solutions/logging). You can use a logging framework such as [log4net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/) to perform the actual logging.